# zypper update package to the previous version (not the last)

Tags: repository, rpm, suse, zypper

How do I **update** (not install) an package **pmc-rpm** from repository **myRepo** to version 10.3.3-1 (but not to the last one!) in SUSE 10.1 command line (zypper)?

So I update the package normally, but this time I have to install the pre-previous package and after that the next and the next and then the last one.

```
zypper update -t package pmc-rpm
```

Comment: Are you sure those packages are still in the repository? I don't know from SuSE but I know that many (if not most or all) RH/CentOS/etc. mirrors don't keep older RPMs around that way.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's may own repository. I can see my packages with command # zypper pa -ir own-repo

Comment: Is the question here how (or can) you specify a specific version of a package to upgrade to? Is the question how to use the `upgrade` sub-command to do this? Something else?

Comment: The question is how can I upgrade the package to specific version like in zypper install package=10.3.3-1 ?

Comment: Why can you not just use `install` for this? The documentation seemed to indicate that `install` will update a package just fine. Does that not work? Does `update` do work that `install` does not? From a quick read of the documentation it looked, to me, like `update` was inferior to `install` in a number of ways.

Comment: Are you sure? I should update the production servers.

Comment: No. I'm not sure. I don't use SuSE. All I have to go on is the documentation I was reading. But that documentation seemed to indicate that they didn't really differ in most ways and that update has restrictions and limitations that aren't listed for install. For the record I was looking at https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29 .

Comment: With newer versions of zypper under OpenSuse 42.3 do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995813/zypper-update-package-to-the-previous-version-not-the-last

Answer (score 4):

So, for package update you can use also **install** parameter.

1. List all package in your repository

   zypper pa -ir repository
2. Then choose the version you need

   zypper in pmc-rpm=10.1.3-1

Thank you folks!

Answer (score 0):

With newer version of zypper you can do:

```
zypper pa -ir repo-name
zypper install --oldpackage package-name-x.x.x.x-x.x86_64
```

E.g. with Skypeforlinux:

```
zypper pa -ir skype-stable
zypper install --oldpackage skypeforlinux-5.5.0.1-1.x86_64
```